# Can I get "svn up" behavior with git?

Tags: git

I use git for most of my new projects and Subversion for legacy projects.

In Subversion, I can checkout a project to two machines (i.e., laptop and desktop).  This way I can make edits in a branch on the laptop and check them in with `svn ci`.  Then on the desktop machine, I can run `svn up` in that branch to pickup the changes.

Is there a similar workflow available with git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would:

- Pull from a common Git repository (the master) (`git pull`)
- Make changes on the laptop, and commit them. You can do this offline. (`git add`, `git commit`)
- Push the changes from the laptop's clone back to the master repository (`git push`)
- Pull from the master repository on the desktop (`git pull`)

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is. The git equivalent to `svn ci` is `git commit -a` followed by `git push`, and the equivalent to `svn up` is `git pull`. Otherwise, it's pretty much the same as with Subversion.

With git, you can also directly pull changes to your laptop from your desktop, if you are able to connect from one to the other with ssh. To do this, on your laptop you would run

```
git pull ssh://user@desktop/path/to/git/working/copy branchname:branchname
```

Or you could run

```
git remote add desktop ssh://user@desktop/path/to/git/working/copy
```

once to set up a named remote, then

```
git pull desktop branchname:branchname
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `git push` similarly to `svn ci`, and `git pull` will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

`svn ci` is approximately `git add` followed by `git commit` (or just use `git commit -a` if  you always commit every changed file).

`svn up` is roughly `git pull`.

Oh, and it sounds like you want a remote tracking branch - look it up, they're well documented.